# Textfield does not work with tinymce widgets

Tags: python, django, widget, tinymce

I wanted to customize my admin file. In admin file I have TextField and I want to use tinymce widget to change its view. All things seem fine because I don't get any error but I don't see effect of my code in admin file. If I delete "field_overrides=..." part I see the normal textfield but with this function I see nothing, completely empty field.

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Tutorial
from django.db import models
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE



class TutorialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ("Title/date", {'fields': ["tutorial_title", "tutorial_published"]}),
        ("Content", {"fields": ["tutorial_content"]})
    ]

    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': TinyMCE}
        }


admin.site.register(Tutorial,TutorialAdmin)
```

This is my model:

```py
from django.db import models
from datetime import  datetime
# Create your models here.
class Tutorial(models.Model):
    tutorial_title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tutorial_content=models.TextField()
    tutorial_published=models.DateTimeField("data published",default=datetime.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tutorial_title
```

here is my settings file(for necessary part):

```py
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'height': 360,
    'width': 1120,
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'modern',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
    }

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'trying.apps.TryingConfig',
    'tinymce',

]
```

Comment: Can you try without `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG` to start with?

Comment: Also, please check in your browser developer tools the source code of your admin page. What do you see where the widget should be? And do you see somewhere the <script src="..."> tags that include tinymce?

Comment: (without default config)It worked but not like I've expected. It showed textfield with some button that enables us to customize it. The problem is that it is really small and does not have too much button option.

Comment: The reason I asked is because the problem might be in your config. Looks like it is indeed the problem. Now add the various options to `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG` line by line (e.g. first just set height and width) to see which part of the config is breaking it. Also, check in your browser developer tools if you see any errors from the tinymce javascript.

Comment: The issue stems from "theme:modern" and 'plugins...' part. Whenever I type them the textfield disappear.

When I have error I checked the browser these are the error messages:"
tiny_mce.js:1 Failed to load: http://localhost:8000/static/tiny_mce/themes/modern/editor_template.js
content.min.js:2 [Deprecation] Element.createShadowRoot is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use Element.attachShadow instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4507242028072960 for more details.
(anonymous) @ content.min.js:2"

Comment: the deprecation warning is just a warning so that shouldn't break anything. But the 'failed to load' error is breaking the js, so that's the problem. You need to get this *editor_template.js* script and add it to the directory mentioned in the error.

Comment: Also regarding the plugins, pretty sure you need to install each of them in the correct location. Check your browser console for missing files and get them from the tinyMCE website. (django-tinymce doesn't include any of TinyMCE itself).

Comment: you are right actually. unless downloading related file I can not get the good view. is there any other things like tinymce that you would recommend me to use it instead of tinymce?

Answer (score 0):

I know is far after time you need the answer but for others with those problem  **'theme': 'modern'**, to **'theme': 'advanced',**  fixed my problem in deployment

Answer (score 0):

Daniel was on track, turned out to be the modern theme. Commented it out in the settings.py TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG and everything is working correctly. Changing it to 'advanced' didn't fix the issue though.

Comment: Hey BioDox . Welcome to StackOverflow Community. KIndly go through the guideline on how to answer before answering. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer